# Using "utilize" instead of "use"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, verbs, writing-style

My friend has been raising a ruckus about the abuse of the word "utilize" in place of the word "use." He complains that it just makes your sentences sound pretentious.

**u·ti·lize** [yoot-l-ahyz]

- verb (used with object), -lized, -liz·ing. 
  to put to use; turn to profitable account: to utilize a stream to power a mill.

<sub>utilize. (n.d.). Dictionary.com Unabridged. Retrieved April 06, 2011, from Dictionary.com website: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/utilize</sub>

Today we saw this [post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7997/is-there-a-minimum-app-price-at-app-stores) which uses "utilize":

> each app vendor may utilize unique policies for app pricing."

He claims that this isn't a very good sentence to use "utilize" in. I don't disagree but what determines whether or not you should use "utilize" in place of "use?"

Comment: How does 'u·ti·lize' become '[yoot-l-ahyz]'?

Comment: There is no sentence that fails to be improved by tossing out *utilize* in favor of *use*.

Comment: @oosterwal Regional pronounciation variations?

Comment: Don't use 'utilize' when you can utilize 'use'.

Comment: @oosterwal it must be caused by noo-kyuh-ler radiation.

Comment: @tchrist 'There is no sentence that fails to be improved by tossing out _use_ in favor of _use_?'

Comment: I _really_ want to edit the title to _"Using 'utilize' instead of utilizing 'use'"_ hmph.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This goes way back. From the [Online Ety. Dict.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=u&p=18):

> 1807, from Fr. utiliser, from It.
>   utilizzare, from utile "usable," from
>   L. utilis "usable," from uti (see use
>   (v.)).

It's used in the sense of "to make profitable use of," as opposed to the bare "use," which just means "to employ." There's a nuance there that speakers have found useful. The only error is the use of "utilize" when "use" alone would suffice.

Comment: +1 for the etymology, but I'd be hard-pressed to call it an error to substitute "utilize" for "use".  It may be a pretentious or inadvisible choice, but it isn't exactly wrong.

Comment: I've followed this debate in the usage guides for years. Here's the deal: When you "utilize" something, you're getting a bit of extra oomph from it. For example: I use my coffee grinder to prepare coffee beans. To powder dried herbs, I utilize my coffee grinder.

Comment: +1 There's certainly an implication of advantage gained when something is "utilized" as opposed to merely being "used". This is a useful distinction to make in the right circumstances, but the example in the original post doesn't fit the bill in my opinion.

Comment: I concur. The example in the original post would have been more happy with "use." The question as asked, however, did not concern that so I didn't address it.

Comment: While ***ultimately*** 'use', 'utilize', and 'utility' all share the same Latin root 'uti', 'use' also has the additional Latin root 'usus'.  The words come to English through Middle French. 'Utilize' is still more closely related to 'utility' that 'use' is.  'Utilize' means to use something in a way other than how it was intended:  "Normally I would *use* a hammer to pound this nail, but I don't have one so I'll *utilize* this brick to pound the nail. You could employ 'use' in this example, but 'utilize' emphasizes the fact that bricks aren't supposed to be used to pound nails.

Comment: @The Raven: It's just occured to me to wonder exactly how you could distinguish "profitable use" from plain old "use". In what sense could you "use" something, if not "profitably"? I assume you're not just assuming "profitable" means "money-making".

Comment: The only error is the utilization of "utilize" when "use" alone would suffice. This error is unforgivable.

Comment: Do you have any source for the 'profitable' bit?  Seems pretty doubtful to me.

Comment: @user1579 People have been marked down for making pretentious / inadvisable choices in essays etc. I'd have to say that such choices usually _are_ wrong. Grammar, basic semantics, and punctuation aren't the _only_ criteria involved.

Answer (score 24):

I don't think there's anything seriously wrong with *utilize* (*utilise* in UK, so forgive me if I revert to type).

But it *is* a little pompous (only a very little, honest). The main reason I personally wouldn't 100% endorse its use here is that *utilise* is (in principle, at least) a somewhat more precise word than *use*. It often implies a degree of creativity in making something *be capable of being used in a way not originally intended*, rather than simply using something designed for the purpose of being thus used.

The vendors’ unique policies are obviously designed for the very use to which they will be put, so I think *utilise* is a bit overdone - slightly tautological, actually.

Comment: I 100% agree - and accordingly the OP's friend is essentially correct with regard to most occurences of "utilise".

Comment: @Marcin: Yes. I didn't specifically point it out in my answer, but I'm afraid the truth is some people use the word *utilise* under the mistaken impression that this gives their statement a touch of 'gravitas'. It doesn't, of course - just makes them look a bit pretentious.

Answer (score 11):

Well, I would turn it round: when there's a nice, short, plain, easily understood word that expresses what you want to say, I would suggest there's no need to use a long, psuedotechnical one instead just for the sake of it.

If you really feel that "utilise" conveys some extra/special meaning in the context in which you're using it, then fair enough. For example, in some contexts (but I think not this one), saying "utilise" rather than "use" may get across the notion of "making special use of something where it wouldn't usually be put to practical use". But if you're just trying to use a long word for the sake of it, then I would suggest that using clear, easy to understand language may be a more effective communication strategy.

The sentence you quote seems to be a classic case of somebody with poor writing skills attempting to sound impressive but in so doing they fail to see the wood for the trees in terms of getting their message across. They really could have just said "Each seller can define how they want to price their apps" and the message would have been to the point and easy to understand.

Comment: Your final sentence seems to imply that the original sentence might *not* be so easy to understand, but that seems unlikely to me. Anyway, it seems all three answers thus far agree on the (potential) difference in meaning for *utilise*, and agree that 'extended' meaning isn't relevant to the example.

Comment: "What's a nice word like you doing in a phrase like this?"

Answer (score 7):

It is advantageous to utilize those linguistic constructs which most emphatically dialog the paradigm conceptualized by the origination entity-person.

Or you could just say what you mean.

I used to work for a company where any reports we wrote for delivery to a customer had to be edited by the company's "deliverable department". They routinely changed every place where I wrote "use" to "utilize" and replaced other short words with longer words. This was done so mechanically that I wouldn't be surprised if they just used the search-and-replace function in Word. I can't imagine any purpose for it other than to sound more pretentious. (I'm not saying there is never a legitimate reason to use the word "utilize", just that a wholesale replacement of "use" with "utilize" is silly.)

(They also once changed a statement about the steps you had to take to "effect a change" to saying you had to do this to "affect a change". Umm, no. The procedure didn't alter the change, it caused it. I guess someone read in a book that lots of people use "effect" as a verb when they mean "affect", and so they blindly changed it without reading or understanding the sentence.)

I've often said that when people set out to write, they tend to have one of two motives. (a) To inform or educate the reader. In this case, they tend to use simple words, clear examples, etc. (b) To impress the reader with how smart the author must be to understand this complicated subject. In this case, they use big words, convoluted examples, etc. People who are really good at (a) leave the reader walking away saying, "Wow, I don't know why people say differential calculus [or whatever] is so hard. It seems pretty logical and straightforward to me." People who are really good at (b) leave the reader walking away saying, "Wow, I never realized how complicated arithmetic really is. I thought I understood it until I read this book. That author must be a genius to understand this stuff; I couldn't make sense of a word of it."

Comment: You mean you "_utilized_ to work for a company"? :)

Answer (score 3):

Why would someone want to use a longer and uglier word when there's a better alternative? ***Utilize*** sounds like a middle manager in an insurance company sending out a memo to the lower echelons while trying to sound important.
Utilize is pretentious and it gets dodgy when you try to add prefixes and suffixes: Underutilized versus underused? 
Abutilized versus abused? 
Underutilization versus underuse?
No contest.

Comment: This is essentially just repeating what the original poster's friend said. Do you have any additional information to back up your claim or bring light to the subject?

Answer (score 2):

The only necessary use I can think of is in 'utilization' which has a specific meaning different from 'usage'

Answer (score 1):

**I tend to think of *utilize* in cases that seem "passive"** - where there is no "user". So for example, we could say: a resource "has been fully utilized." This sidesteps the question of "by whom?" which is not relevant to the discussion.

It also leans toward the meaning of *utility* rather than the verb sense of *consuming*. The resource in question was "advantageously spent" rather than "put in to action". It seems very passive to me. The emphasis is on *how much* has been used rather than how it was used.

Answer (score -1):

I remember researching the difference between "utilize" and "use" several years ago and finding a sensible and useful answer. I've applied that answer ever since but, for whatever reason, can't find it online anymore. It could be that it's wrong, but I doubt it.

---

### use

> the act or practice of employing something
>
> ~ https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/use
>
> examples (mine):
>
> - "The stadium is used for sporting events."
> - "The car was used to take them to the airport."
> - "I'm using the hammer to nail down the roof tiles."

### utilize

> to use something for a purpose other than its intended purpose
>
> ~ me (based on previous research)
>
> examples:
>
> - "The stadium is being utilized as a shelter for hurricane victims."
> - "The car was utilized to stabilize the tree."
> - "I'm utilizing the hammer as a paper weight."

In short, I believe that "utilize" is a sub-category of "use". It has a narrower definition.

Comment: For an example, compare "Sarah used the floss to clean between her teeth." with "Lacking proper floss, Sarah utilized some thread from her sewing kit."