# Correct sense of "practical"

Tags: meaning

The definition of *utilize* is

> to use something, especially for a practical purpose.

What does *practical* mean here? Definitions of *practical* from OALD:

> connected with real situations rather than with ideas or theories
>
> right or sensible; likely to be successful
>
> useful or suitable
>
> sensible and realistic

Comment: This question is an attempt to get at the difference between *use* (v.) and *utilize (v.) and so is an exact duplicate of <http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19811/using-utilize-instead-of-use>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noted in a comment that *utilize* appears frequently in theoretical discussions, not necessarily sensible, realistic, or likely to succeed; and that most use of the term entails using something in a way it is suitable for, as in sense 3, “useful or suitable”.  More precisely, the third sense is the one whose elements are common to almost all uses of *practical* in the context of defining  *utilize*, although in *many* uses of *practical* in that context, elements of all four senses apply.

In [an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/19814/11433) to a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19811/using-utilize-instead-of-use)  about *utilize*, FumbleFingers submits that using *utilize* is at least in principle “a somewhat more precise word than *use*. It often implies a degree of creativity in making something be capable of being used in a way not originally intended, rather than simply using something designed for the purpose of being thus used” – which, note, does not contravene the item being found suitable for its new purpose –  and also says *utilize* is only a little pompous.  Other answers go further; *eg* Jay suggests it's used “To impress the reader with how smart the author must be to understand this complicated subject”.

Answer (score 0):

*Practical* in the meaning of "right or sensible; likely to be successful — even profitable".

Sample sentences:

> - We must consider how best to utilize what resources we have.
> - The vitamins come in a form that is easily utilized by the body.