# Utilise or Utilize

Tags: british-english, ise-ize

I am writing in UK English and would like to confirm that we use utilise instead of utilize. I cannot seem to find a answer for this online.

Comment: I'd think in British English we'd say _use_.

Comment: @Brian Hooper I'm in the states, but the OED definition suggests that utilize is slightly different (though, my impression is that most of the time *utilize* is misused) *utilize*: to make or render useful; to convert to use, turn to account
—Oxford English Dictionary

Comment: Collins lists [both](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/utilize) in their English edition, and only [one](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/American/utilize) in their American edition. [This link](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/utilise) might help you, too.

Comment: Look up ise ize using the search function.

Comment: @batpigandme: I don't know where you get that "slightly different" impression from. Current OED (online, which I can access, but can't link to) doesn't even *have* an entry for *utilise*. The only reference to the s-spelling I can see is that under the main heading it says *Forms:  Also **utilise***.

Comment: It would be the *utilise* spelling. All of the words that end in the sound that rhymes with the word *eyes*, such as this one, are normally spelt with *ise*, in the UK.

Comment: @FumbleFingers http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/utilize

Comment: @FumbleFingers not exactly the same as the version I originally referenced as that one is hard copy. Either way, it's definitely "American English"

Comment: @batpigandme: I'm not sure it's necessarily true in this case that s=UK, z=US. My trusty Chambers is probably more pro-UK spelling than OED, but it also gives the "utilize" spelling *first*. My personal feeling is that with most of these *-ise/-ize* words it's fair to say the *-ise* versions are almost exclusively British - but the *-ize* versions are effectively "generic", and now acceptable almost everywhere.

Comment: Nice article at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29 (though the title is perhaps a little misleading).

Comment: @batpigandme I have to agree with FumbleFingers. I'm surprised to find that Chambers, ODO (BrEng) & Collins all give *utilize* as the first spelling, and MacMillan (cited by J.R.) gives it as *a* British spelling (from which I infer that *both* spellings are used in the UK). I too would have expected *utilise* to be the British spelling.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I didn't think batpig was saying there's a difference between _utilize_ and _utilise_, but that there was a difference between _utilize_ and _use_. It's an answer to Brian's comment.

Comment: @TrevorD: The Wikipedia article indicates that -ise : -ize does occur in the ratio 3 : 2 in the BNC, but that certain publishers do not reflect this in their recommendations. In fact, "The OED lists the -ise form separately, as "a frequent spelling of -IZE", and refuses to list the -ise spellings even as alternatives in the individual entries for words such as realize."

Comment: @J.R.: oic. Well that one has been [covered here before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19811/)

Comment: I once spelled it "utilise," and someone commented that I was using the British spelling. So I (in the states) use "utilize" now. I thought that I did before, but I guess I was spelling it both ways for a while...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In most words containing the ending, both -*ise* and -*ize* are acceptable in British English. Oxford University Press (which publishes all the Oxford Dictionaries) is well known as preferring -*ize*, but most other British publishers and authorities prefer -*ise*.

Comment: This is correct.  Oxford press prefer -ize and Cambridge press prefer -ise.  It is traditionally more British to use -ise, but as both are accepted, -ize is international and it often makes sense to conform rather than alienate, unless you want a particularly British aesthetic.

Comment: @Sam, "aesthetic"? That the right word?

Comment: I completely agree.  People should conform with English.