# Single word for "make good use of something"

Tags: single-word-requests

Does a single word for "make good use of" exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest **utilise**

I instinctively spell this ending in -ise, but *utilize* is the common spelling internationally. I found this useful entry which elaborates further;

[Utilise or Utilize](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114269/utilise-or-utilize)

For example, "He utilised his experience in order to solve the problem".

From [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/utilize)

> to make practical or worthwhile use of

Answer (score 0):

> leverage

would be another word, but not applicable to all the contexts, it means to take advantage of already existing things in a useful way, while **utilize** might mean to use it for any needed purpose even if it implies a long process of preparing a new thing from the existing one.